# SwiperJS - Grid / Row option gives incorrect ordering of elements

Tags: swiper.js

Trying to replicate the following using the latest version of SwiperJS.  Basically, we have slides that hold 6 posts. This is laid out in 2x rows of 3 and are ordered by date. So...

**Slide 1**

1 2 3
4 5 6

**Slide 2**

7 8 9
10 11 12

While I can get the layout sorted using the options provided by Swiper, the ordering is really weird.

Have set up a Codepen:

https://codepen.io/powen-cs/pen/BabZgqp

This has the correct layout, using the Grid parameter set to `row`, however what it's outputting is the following:

**Slide 1**

1 2 3
6 7 8

**Slide 2**

4 5
9 10

... which looks like the ordering carries on in row 1 onto slide 2.

If I change the Grid parameter to `column`, I get the closest to what I want, however the order is still out:

**Slide 1**

1 3 5
2 4 6

**Slide 2**

7 9 11
8 10 12

... which is close, but not quite.

I've tried all sorts of approaches, from trying different CSS Flex options to SlidePerGroup in Swiper to try achieve the above to no avail.  As this is for WordPress posts, I *could* try counting posts and adding them to a slide then using flex to position them, then count X again for the next slide... but it just feels like Swiper should be able to do it somehow.

Any ideas / suggestions are appreciated.